# class B inside class A inherits class A

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, inner-classes

I tried the following and failed to compile.

```
class A {
   
   //...members

   class B : public A {    //<---failed here
      using A::A;
      
   }
   
}
```

Is this possible(specially in c++17)? Do this just have wrong syntax?
If not possible, why this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, but the definition of `B` needs to be moved outside of `A`. Until the closing brace, `A` is an incomplete type, whereas the base class must be complete.

This would work:

```
class A {
   class B;
};

class A::B : public A {
    using A::A;
};
```

Comment: wow! good thing i ask here. i don't know that inner class can be defined later even before c++11. :)